# Pass by reference VS Pass by value

Tags: c++, performance, function, parameters

I was reading [this](http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/73-passing-arguments-by-reference/) but  now I am confused with efficiency of two ways to pass parameters.

Compared with pass by value, this tutorial told me that pass by reference is fast "because a copy of the argument is not made". However, it also told me that "dereferencing a pointer(reference) is slower than accessing it directly, accessing values passed by reference is slower than accessing values passed by value".

So here is my question: if pass by reference faster or slower than pass by value?

Thanks!

Comment: on the cost of making the copy of the value.  Balanced against the cost of having to dereference a pointer to obtain the value.  If you have no idea then experiment with a profiler.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on the size of passed variable.

If it's in example `char` then it's faster to make a copy cause it usually takes 1 B, when reference on x32 can take around 4 B on x32,
but when you pass in example a `std::string`, situation is the opposite - AFAIK maximum `string`'s size is limited only by your system's architecture and your hardware.